# How can i create buttons from database field in VB?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I use Mysql database. I want to create new buttons in vb.net for every data.

When i add new member from admin panel, it must create new button in vb.net.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any control, including buttons dynamically to Control's collection:

At the very basic it looks something like this:

```
Dim myButton As New Button

MyButton.Id = "btnMyButton"
MyButton.Text = "New Button"

Me.Controls.Add(MyButton)
```

The values for Id and Text can come from your DB. You will also probably want button something to do - you can add handler for "OnClick" event using "AddHandler" statement.

The approach described above is somewhat universal, but depending on whether you use ASP.NET or WinForms - additional details may need to be coded.